# How to find the square root of perfect square?

Tags: scala

I'm working on this simple task implementing this function trying to find the square root of a perfect square in Scala, and then I'm testing it with this simple test method. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
def squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a: Int): Option[Int] = 
  if (scala.math.sqrt(a) % 1 == 0) 
    scala.math.sqrt(a)
  else 
    -1
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you are declaring the result type of your function as `Option[Int]`, but trying to return `Double` (`scala.math.sqrt(a)`) from it.

Comment: Im still new to scala. Im not sure what Option[Int] does...also my function already came with Option[Int] and Im suppose to implement... any ideas how to implement it right?

Comment: Read this for example: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-scala-option-some-none-idiom-function-java-null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return `Some` or `None` when you specify return type as `Option[T]`.

```
def squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a: Int): Option[Int] = {
  val sqrt = math.sqrt(a)
  if (sqrt % 1 == 0)
    Some(sqrt.toInt)
  else
    None
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a: Int): Option[Int] = {
val sqrt = math.sqrt(a)
if (math.sqrt(a).ceil == math.sqrt(a))
   Some(sqrt.toInt)
else
   None
 }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way is to stay in the Int world to avoid any rounding and precision issue with double

```
def squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a: Int): Option[Int] = {
  int sqrt = (int) Math.round(math.sqrt(a));
  if (sqrt * sqrt == a)
    Some(sqrt)
  else
    None
}
```